# Change CSS value by using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

For example, I have this CSS script:

```
<style>
.header{
background:none:
color:#fff;
}
</style>
```

Then, I would like to change the header value to:

```
<style>
.header{
background-color:#fff:
color:#000;
}
</style>
```

The values are stored in database. What makes me confused is which should be the best to do that: Using PHP script or CSS or even javascript.
I want it changed based on the CSS value from my database which I can change again when I need it (by using PHP script). Perhaps this question is too general but, please give me some scripts which I can perform it well.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look here; http://www.kirupa.com/html5/setting_css_styles_using_javascript.htm

Comment: You can have two classes one default and one inverse. In the header  you can add class inverse if a condition is met. Something like this `<div class=”default <?php echo $flag ? ‘’ : ‘inverse’;?>>`

Comment: what's wrong with scss or less?

Comment: if you want to grab data from database then you need to use php for that and to apply that data to css you can use jquery or Javascript

Comment: I recommend to watch this video by Getify (Kyly Simpson) - might point you in some interesting direction: http://vimeo.com/99916682 (tl;dr; CSS templating)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first, change the extension of your file from (e.g.) style.css to style.php . Then add this to the first line of your css:

`<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>`

and after that you can define the value of your background as a variable and change it easily.

`background: <?php echo $value; ?>`

and in your php file:

`<?php value = "#fff"; ?>`

UPDATE:

```
<?php $value = "#fff"; ?>
```

Comment: is it okay to change the extension? it's strange for me. does browser recognize it as css or php?

Comment: is this method working?

Answer (score 2):

For maintainability and flexibility reasons, I want to propose the frontend, not a backend solution (also because so far nobody proposed that).

I especially like the approach taken in the [Grips library](https://github.com/getify/grips), where you can compile CSS template, passing in variables as an input (i.e. colors), and get the CSS to use. All of that can happen in the browser. And you can use Grips for HTML templating as well.

As I mentioned in the comment, [this video](http://vimeo.com/99916682) is the best introduction to Grips.

Also note that if you want to use Grips in the backend, you can - but it's a JS library, so it wouldn't fit perfectly into your PHP solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think its same for both way.

If you want to use php then you will have to use inline css or style tag and its simple to.

Like

```
$color = (!dbValue?"defaule value":dbValue);

<style>
.header{
background-color:<?=$color?>:
color:#000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a php page in that write

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select * from table'));


<style>
    .header{ 
        background-color: <?php echo $row['bg_color_from_db']; ?> //change variable
        color:<?php echo $row['color_from_db']; ?>; //change variable
    }
</style>
```

Comment: As soon as the number of variables increases, maintaining that would be painful.

Comment: data retrieval was not the problem, it your convenience to retrieve the data but main is how to use the data you get from DB and use in PHP and vote up if you found the satisfied solution

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you will need to use all three together, I am assuming you are using a LAMP set up on the back end. You will use PHP to first retrieve the values and store them, here is a good post to show this.

[Link to Example on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083089/use-php-code-in-external-javascript-file)

Once you have your values stored you will then need to create a file to change the DOM using JavaScript. Here is a good starting point produced by Mozilla Developers:

[Mozilla JavaScript and CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/JavaScript)

The reason I suggest using JavaScript to achieve this is the ability to listen for events and change the client side in response. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Import your database here In css or include db page;

```
$bg_color=$_row['column name'];
background-color:$bg_color;
```

And something like this you will be able to change your Background color using the value stored in database

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WordPress, you could add an action that would write your styles into the document head. The styles can be made conditional on whatever PHP conditions you like:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_styles' );
function my_custom_styles() {
    ob_start();
        ?>
        <style id="my-custom-styles" type="text/css">
            <?php if ( condition is met ) : ?>
                 .header{ background-color: #fff; color: #000;
            <?php else : ?>
                 .header{ background: none; color: #fff; }
            <?php endif; ?>
        </style>
        <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

You could even write the styles with PHP variables:

```
.header{ background: none; color: <?php echo esc_attr( $variable ) ?>}
```