# How can I change button color based on database table value in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I created button like this:

```
<button type = "submit" name="one" class="button button1">B-1</button>
```

It makes table value 1 from 0 after a click. But button color remains same. Now I want to change the button color with change of table value. #TIA

Comment: <button type = "submit" name="one" class="button button1">B-1</button>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change CSS value by using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636527/change-css-value-by-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

When you get your data from your database you can add a class to each button based on the field value, and create a CSS class that styles that button.

For example, let's say your `B-1` button with the name 'one' changes the field `checked` with the name same as the button's name in your table.

| name | checked |
| --- | --- |
| one | 1 |
| two | 0 |

When you load your page and query the table with PHP (e.g. `mysqli_query("select checked from my_table where name='one'")`) and fetch the data, you can do the following:

```
<button type="submit" name="one" class="button button1 checked-<?php echo $query_result['checked']; ?>">B-1</button>
```

Assuming you have stored your query result in `$query_result`, checked should either be `1` or `0`, therefore adding a class with the name `checked-0` or `checked-1`.

Then, in your CSS file or `<style>` tag add two classes:

```
.checked-0{color:red;}
.checked-1{color:green;}
```