# PHP DOM on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dom

Can we do

```
var name = <?PHP $_POST["name" ?>
```

on .js file?

So I want to get the $_POST value of php to make use of it in my javascript, because php lack of `document.getElementById("id");`

Comment: global variable var name =  '<?php echo  $_POST["name"];  ?>';

Comment: NO. You can use a global var at the php and that can be accessed at js file then.

Comment: Do you want to work with `var name` later on or just want to include the `$_POST["name"]` into the dom? Why not just writing `<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>` inside the html structure and taking that value/dom with e.g. query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include PHP inside JavaScript (.js) files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083089/use-php-code-in-external-javascript-file

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574306/executing-php-code-inside-a-js-file

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928827/access-php-var-from-external-javascript-file

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment you can use a global variable to store the value and that variable can be used in the js file:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var name = '<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>'; // <---should be wrapped in quotes
  </script>
  <script src="jsfile.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Now in the js file you can make a reference to this variable:

```
var user = name; // window.name;
```

Comment: Little modification - ```var name = '<?php echo $_POST["name"];  ?>';```

Comment: thnx @mi6crazyheart

Comment: @Ivar hohoho! what a miss.

Answer (score 0):

no but you can make javascript file like javascript.php and put the following like on top of file

```
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

and write javascript code in this file also then php code